# How to restrict the css star selector * to a class and all decendants?

Tags: html, css

I am using the following css class selector for "fixing" sizing issues:

```
*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

In the above for it applies to the entire DOM. For the embeddable Web component I an writing this is inappropriate as it can easily play havoc with the hosting Web app. I want the restrict these to a `div` with a specific class - lets call the class `.knuth-style` for grins - as well as all descendent elements. What is the syntax for writing this?

### UPDATE 0

Ok, here's the thing I am happy to give Nit the ole check mark here but ... his solution does **not** actually work. Specifically - with the actual css class name I am using:

```
.grid-container-colorpicker, .grid-container-colorpicker:after, .grid-container-colorpicker:before
.grid-container-colorpicker *, .grid-container-colorpicker *:after, .grid-container-colorpicker *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Not a pretty sight. Discuss?

### UPDATE 1

Not as direct as a jsfiddle - too unweildly to excise the relevant bits - but I have something as good or better. The complete css class assignment for the DOM sub-tree in question.

Here is before using just the kleene star (all elements):
[image]

And here is Nil's suggested solution:
[image]

### UPDATE 2

Ok, after a bit of css class renaming, Nil's solution is essentially correct. The one caveat: a rule of the form:

```
.knuth-style *, .knuth-style *:after, .knuth-style *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

does not appear to work. However using a class attribute approach does:

```
[class*='knuth-'], [class*='knuth-']:after, [class*='knuth-']:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I had to resort to pre-pending identical css class name prefixes to all decendent classes. No biggy.

Comment: `.knuth-style, .knuth-style *, .knuth-style *:after, .knuth-style *:before`

Comment: Apply `border-box` only when you really need it.

Comment: @JackPattishall - OP wants `.knuth-style` *and* its descendants styled, per title. This version only targets the descendants.

Comment: Are you really asking about simple descendant selectors, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: @RoboRobok Applying it via `*` is a common practice, what side-effects are you worried about?

Comment: Yea but `*` is such a slow selector when used by itself

Comment: @Huangism CSS selector speed in general is the last micro-optimization you have to worry about if you write reasonably good selectors most of the time.

Comment: @Nit yea if you need to use then use it but I try to avoid it as much as I can.

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 yea it's slower, `*` vs `html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, tab...` http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/csscreate.php set the number of rules to 1, using those 2 selectors

Comment: If it doesn't work then you'll have to show your actual DOM. It's possible the style is overruled by something more specific from another stylesheet.

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 the `*` run 10 times slower for me

Comment: The rules you said did and didn't work in your final edit are **different** rules, they target different elements (class naming aside). One targets children, one targets elements themselves.

Comment: Yes Nil. My point is that I was not able to get your syntax - .knuth-style * - to work. So I abandoned that approach and brute forced it with a common prefix for all children and just used the simple class attribute approach. Simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add the necessary selectors?

```
.knuth-style, .knuth-style:after, .knuth-style:before 
.knuth-style *, .knuth-style *:after, .knuth-style *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Oh, one "nice to have" would be the ability to use a class attribute selector [class*="rootname-"] to make my css a bit less cluttered. I assume I can simply swap that in place of .knuth-style. Yes?